# Convert varbinary data in DB to Bitmap, manipulate, then render in SSRS report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I'm building a report in Microsoft Report Builder and need to take images from the database, manipulate them, then display them in the report.  I'm having trouble with step one in this process, which is verify I can convert the varbinary to a bitmap, and then convert it back and render it in the report.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
Public Function EditImage(ByVal picbytes as Byte()) as Byte()

    Dim ms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim rms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim bm as System.Drawing.Bitmap

    ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(picbytes, 0, picbytes.Length)
    bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

        ' Image manipulation code will go here

    bm.Save(rms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Return rms.ToArray()
End Function
```

Here's how I'm calling it in the image control in the report:

```
=Lookup(Fields!ImageID.Value,Fields!ImageID.Value, System.Convert.ToBase64String(Code.EditImage(Fields!Media.Value)),"Media")
```

For some reason, this is causing the image to fail to display when I run the report.  If I ignore the code and return picbytes in the function, the image displays.  So the issue appears to be with how I am converting to a Bitmap and then converting back to a Byte array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the point of EditImage?  It just shuffles the data from an array to a memstream to bitmap to new memstream back to an array.  It does nothing.

Comment: You are correct.  Eventually I will be adding some code to conditionally rotate the image and perform some other actions.  See the "Image manipulation code will go here" comment in the function.  Before I go too much further with that, I need to verify that I can properly convert the varbinary data to a Bitmap so it can be manipulated, and then convert it back to a byte array so SSRS can render it.  Which is where my problem is right now.

Comment: I think you need to pass your memory stream into an Image.fromstream function.

Comment: Tried replacing the bitmap with an image and using FromStream.  Same results.  Converting to an image then back to a memorystream appears to break it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  Needed to new up the second memory stream.  The following code works:

```
Public Function EditImage(ByVal picbytes as Byte()) as Byte()

    Dim ms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim rms as System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim bm as System.Drawing.Bitmap

    ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(picbytes)
    bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

        ' Image manipulation code will go here

    rms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
    bm.Save(rms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Return rms.ToArray()
End Function
```